# Exclude a Controller from Default Route C# MVC

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'd like to prevent a route from handling one of my controllers, called `MyController`.

I thought this might work, but it doesn't:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{urlId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", urlId = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = @"^(!?MyController)$" }
);
```

Sadly it stops me from navigating to any of my controllers.

I can only get it not to match if the controller contains `MyController` using `(!?MyController.*)` but this isn't matching it exactly.

All of the regex testers I've tried suggest that it should only match **exactly** `MyController`.

Comment: Hi.  Its the first mapped route.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found this here http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints

Create the NotEqual class to use in your constraints

```
public class NotEqual : IRouteConstraint
{
  private string _match = String.Empty;

  public NotEqual(string match)
  {
    _match = match;
  }

  public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
  {
    return String.Compare(values[parameterName].ToString(), _match, true) != 0;
  }
}
```

Then use the class in your RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{urlId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", urlId = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = new NotEqual("MyController") }
);
```

Comment: @Coulton Just so you know, because MVC is convention driven, in most places where you have to specify a controller, you don't have to type out the word controller, MVC knows to look for a controller prepended with what you specify.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm a bit confused about omitting the controller bit, how would that work in this example?

Comment: @Luke you could use `new NotEqual("My")`

Comment: If your controller is named "MyController", most of the time, you can just pass "My" as parameter, MVC automatically adds "Controller" when looking for the controller. That's what JB06 was explaining.

Comment: Ahh ok then.  I'm not sure whether that is the case for this example, it does a string.Compare() against the controller value.  Does that mean that the framework runs NotEqual's `Match()` method for the string `My` and `MyController` and other conventions?  It's not the MVC code doing the matching, it's our custom code in our `IRouteConstraint` implementation